# Optional<Long> to Optional<Instant>

Tags: java, option-type, long-integer, java.time.instant

i have to convert  an Option to Optional, and created the  code for this but i believe it could be even shorter that  the private method is not used.

```
Optional<Long> optionalLong  ;
 Optional<Instant> optionalInstant;


assertThat(createdOrder.acceptedTime, is( OptionalLongToOptionalInstant(expectedOrder.acceptedTime())));


private Optional<Instant> OptionalLongToOptionalInstant(Optional<Long> optionalLong ) {
    if(optionalLong.isPresent()){
        return   Optional.of(Instant.ofEpochMilli(optionalLong.get()));
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Comment: How oome `acceptedTime()` doesn’t return an [`OptionalLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/OptionalLong.html)?

Answer (score 4):

You should use [`Optional.map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method:

> If a value is present, apply the provided mapping function to it, and if the result is non-null, return an Optional describing the result. Otherwise return an empty Optional.

```
Optional<Long> optionalLong  = Optional.ofNullable(createdOrder.acceptedTime());
Optional<Instant> optionalInstant = optionalLong.map(Instant::ofEpochMilli);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.map()` method is what you need

```
assertThat(createdOrder.acceptedTime, is(expectedOrder.acceptedTime().map(Instant::ofEpochMilli)));
```

---

Source code, it does check for you the `isPresent()` :

```
public <U> Optional<U> map(Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapper) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(mapper);
    if (!isPresent()) {
        return empty();
    } else {
        return Optional.ofNullable(mapper.apply(value));
    }
}
```